# Visual Studio 2015 WinAPI error on MessageBox

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2015, tchar, lpcwstr

I created a basic Windows C++ application in Visual Studio 2015 and I have a few errors:

[image: Erorrs image]

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Test_text", "Message Test", MB_ICONINFORMATION | MB_OKCANCEL);
    return 0;
}
```

**Errors:**

> ```
> 'int MessageBoxW(HWND,LPCWSTR,LPCWSTR,UNIT)': cannot convert argument 2 from 
> 'const char [10]' to 'LPCWSTR'
>
> argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR"
> argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR"
> ```

Comment: Don't show errors or code via images (inline or externally linked). Always show the full text of the error here as text.

Comment: And if you'd search for the message text, you would have found the solution already.

Answer (score 5):

You choose to use ANSI text, so you should use `MessageBoxA` explicitly instead of macro `MessageBox`.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "Test_text", "Message Test", MB_ICONINFORMATION | MB_OKCANCEL);
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you may use`TEXT` macro to have the compiler automatically match type of strings and functions.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Test_text"), TEXT("Message Test"), MB_ICONINFORMATION | MB_OKCANCEL);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is the Win32 **`TCHAR` model**.

There's actually no `MessageBox` function: `MessageBox` is a *preprocessor* `#define`, that expands to `MessageBoxA` or `MessageBoxW`, based on your project settings (ANSI/MBCS or Unicode, respectively).

Starting with VS2005, the *default* setting in Visual Studio has been **Unicode** (to be more precise: **UTF-16**). So the `MessageBoxW` API (i.e. the Unicode version) is picked in this case by the compiler.

The `MessageBoxW` API takes **Unicode (UTF-16) strings**, represented via `wchar_t` pointers (the obscure `LPCWSTR` preprocessor macro is expanded to `const wchar_t*`, i.e. a `NUL`-terminated C-style Unicode UTF-16 string).

Unicode (UTF-16) string literals are represented using the **`L"..."`** syntax (note the **L prefix**).
So, while `"Test_text"` is an ANSI string literal, `L"Test_text"` is a Unicode (UTF-16) string literal.

Since your are (implicitly, via Visual Studio default settings) doing a Unicode build, you should decorate your string literals with the **L prefix**, e.g.:

```
MessageBox(nullptr,   // <--- prefer nullptr to NULL in modern C++ code 
           L"Test_text",      // <--- Unicode (UTF-16) string literal 
           L"Message Test",   // <--- Unicode (UTF-16) string literal
           MB_ICONINFORMATION | MB_OKCANCEL);
```

An alternative is to decorate the string literals using the [`_T("...")` or `TEXT("...")` macros](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040212-00/?p=40643/). These will be expanded to simple `"..."` ANSI string literals in ANSI/MBCS builds, and to Unicode (UTF-16) string literals `L"..."` in Unicode builds (which are the default in modern versions of Visual Studio).

```
// TEXT("...") works in both ANSI/MBCS and Unicode builds
MessageBox(nullptr, 
           TEXT("Test_text"),    
           TEXT("Message Test"),
           MB_ICONINFORMATION | MB_OKCANCEL);
```

Personally, I consider the TCHAR model an obsolete model from the past (I see no reason to produce ANSI builds of modern C++ Win32 applications), and considering that modern Windows APIs are Unicode-only (e.g. [`DrawThemeText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773312(v=vs.85).aspx)), I'd just decorate strings literals using the `L"..."` prefix, and kind of forget about the ANSI builds.

Comment: When passing wide character string literals, you should explicitly call the wide character version of the API (i.e. `MessageBoxW` instead of `MessageBox`).

Comment: @IInspectable: I don't agree. `MessageBoxW` (or `DoSomethingW` in general) is an useless _code uglification_ in Unicode builds: the ending `W` is just noise over the clearer `MessageBox` (or `DoSomething`) form.

Comment: This is not about opinions, it's about language rules. `MessageBox` is the generic text mapping version. `MessageBoxW` is the Unicode version. I would take what you believe to be *"uglification"* over relying on an environment outside my control any day.

Comment: I understand your reasoning about `MessageBox` being a mapping, but if my code doesn't need to be built in ANSI mode, I prefer `MessageBox` with `L"..."`, which has the positive side-effect of breaking compilation if someone tries to do an ANSI build (instead of UNICODE build).

Comment: There's nothing positive about breaking code due to incompatible formal parameters and arguments passed to a function. It's worse, still: If you aren't explicit about the function you wish to call, you might not be calling the function you intended to call altogether. When passing `nullptr` the compiler won't help you. It'll just let you accidentally call a function you never meant to call. Using the preprocessor symbols for the generic text mappings instead of the real function names doesn't have a single advantage going for it. Stop proposing it based on false claims.

Comment: @IInspectable: I don't get what you mean about passing `nullptr`. I'm talking about string literals. As I said, I see no problems in using the more readable `DoSomething` API instead of the more noisy `DoSomethingW` in Unicode builds, with `L"..."` string literals (to be honest, I prefer loading string from resources for better localization, so there aren't much literals). This is my position, yours may be different. Enough for me (this is starting to sound like where to put braces or how much indenting code).

Answer (score 4):

MessageBox in this case is actually MessageBoxW, it takes unicode strings. You can fix it in this way:

```
MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Test_text", L"Message Test", MB_ICONINFORMATION | MB_OKCANCEL);
```

or

```
MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Test_text"), TEXT("Message Test"), MB_ICONINFORMATION | MB_OKCANCEL);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass a bare string literal like that.

```
MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Test_text"), TEXT("Message Test"), MB_ICONINFORMATION | MB_OKCANCEL);
```

`TEXT` is a macro that expands to the right string type depending the way you compile.

Comment: `_T` is for use with CRT and `TEXT` is for use with Windows API, so using `TEXT` is better in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose the correct setting for the `Character Set` for your project. In the properties of your Visual Studio Project, navigate to the `General` category. In there is an entry `Character Set`.

If you choose `Unicode Character Set` the compiler will define `_UNICODE` for you and all functions like `MessageBox` will evaluate to their wide-character variant, like `MessageBoxW`.

If you choose `Multi-Byte` (deprecated) the compiler will define `_MBCS` for you and the functions will evaluate to the multi-byte variants, like `MessageBoxA`.

The same comes in for strings, the macros mentioned in the answers (like `TEXT`) will add an `L` in front of all your strings in a unicode environment.

See here for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ey142t48.aspx

IMHO there are very few reasons where one wants to write explicitly against the `W` or `A` methods. If you have to do that to make your compiler happy, you should recheck your settings.